# How to clear SearchBar result and show full data in tableview using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar

My Scenario, I am loading `JSON` data into `tableview` here I am maintaining two segment controller button for single `tableview` with `search-bar`. First segment button click to search I can get search result well and if I click segment button two there is also showing same search result. So, when I click segment one to two I need to clear search result and load normal data. Same scenario working well when I click close button within `searchBar`.

My Code

```
@IBAction func switchTableviewAction(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

        switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            print(“one”)
            self.searchResultClear()
            currentTableView = sender.selectedSegmentIndex
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        case 1:
            print(“two”)
            self.searchResultClear()
            currentTableView = sender.selectedSegmentIndex
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    // MARK: Search Result Clear working but not clearing result 
    func searchResultClear() {
        //self.searchBar.text = ""
        //self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
        //self.filteredLanguages.removeAll()
        //self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: What is the data source for the table view?

Comment: You can use a variable of type Boolean to maintain the state if user is searching or not. And based on that variable you can show full data in tableview when user is not searching

Comment: Can you please provide me some more detail code? @KeyurTailor

Comment: You have to filter the results and assign it to `filteredLanguages` array again.

Comment: @Kamran my question is how to clear filtered results after clicking my segement button. which is search bar X button doing operation. same I need to do. give me some code example.

Comment: When you press x button, the text of search bar changed to blank (i.e ""). So you can use textdidchange delegate method of UISearchBar. Compare the searchText variable of delegate with empty string. And do the required operations inside the if condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Along with clearing search bar, you also need to remove the filtering from data source. By data source, I mean the array of objects you are showing in table view. You must be using a filter function with the filter text. If you want to clear the search bar, you also need to restore the original JSON data (the unfiltered one) and then call `reloadData`

Comment: Great explanation. I am using two Array one is for JSON and another one is for filter. Finally filter I am using all the places. Now within this segbutton action what I want to do for clear action?

Comment: use the unfiltered array with which you are showing your data

Comment: you must close the question once it is answered

Answer (score 1):

You just need to call the `searchBar textDidChange` method with empty text when segment control selection is changed

```
@IBAction func switchTableviewAction(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        self.searchBar(self.searchBar, textDidChange: "")
    case 1:
        self.searchBar(self.searchBar, textDidChange: "")
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @RajeshKumar. I am done it by using some other method earlier.